# Finding optimal trajectory truck with constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control

I have a truck model with the following state space vector:
$$ \underline{x} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  x\\
  y\\
  \theta\\
  \alpha
\end{array}
\right] $$
$$u=\phi$$

Where the control input is the steering angle.

This system obeys the following differential equation:
$$ \underline{\dot{x}} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  \cos(\theta)\\
  \sin(\theta)\\
  \frac{\tan(\phi)}{l}\\
  -\left(\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{l_t}+\frac{\tan(\phi)}{l}\right)
\end{array}
\right] $$

I have a trajectory composed of $\underline{x_{i}} \quad \forall i=0,...,N$ where $\underline{x_{N}}$ is the goal configuration and $\underline{x_{0}}$ is the starting configuration. I want to smooth my current trajectory as it is very curvy but for doing so I need to develop the minimization algorithm, which currently looks like:

$$\min_{\phi_0,\dots \phi_N}\int_{0}^{N} \phi^2 \, d\phi$$
$$\text{subject to} \quad \mathbf{\dot{x}}=f(\underline{{x}},u)$$
$$|u| < 0.55 \quad \operatorname{rad}$$
$$\underline{x}[N]=\underline{x}_\text{goal}$$

And I want to keep the initial $\underline{x_{0}}$ as it is. Both the minimization function and the constraints are non-convex. The problem I face is that I do not know how to represent the system in order to plug it to a minimization tool as I want to use the current set of $\underline{x_{i}}$ as an initial guess and apply some kind of Gradient method to it in order to **smooth** the trajectory while keeping the constraints. I was thinking about linearizing the differential equation and plug the initial guess for the starting position but with this approach I would not consider the rest of current data points that I have. I would appreciate as well recommendations about tools that would help me to deal with this problem in the easiest way possible.

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBszP.png) depicts the current trajectory that I have where I would like to smooth some unnecessary turns done near the green object and to do that I would minimize the steering of the truck and keeping initial and final state vector as they originally are but I want to use my current trajectory (the whole) as a starting point and iteratively minimize on top of it.

Comment: As the problem is stated, it is not clear to me, if it is a problem of interpolation or smoothing. Also, are the assigned points associated with due time?

Comment: It is a smoothing problem. The points have an order as they define a trajectory of a vehicle but no time is assigned as I am just applying constant speed so not care much about time, just about obtain some geometrical curve that makes me fulfill dynamical constraints

Comment: According  to your  formulation, calling $v = \frac{\tan\phi}{l}$ the proposed system is equivalent to

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x \\
\dot y \\
\dot\theta
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\cos\theta \\
\sin\theta \\
0
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}
\right)v,\ \ \ \dot\alpha = -\frac{\sin\alpha}{l_t}-v
$$

Comment: Sorry to bother but this change I think does not help me in plugging the dynamics into a optimizer. I mean do you know a optimizer I can pass this dynamics of the vehicle, a initial trajectory that I have with an array of [x,y,theta,alpha] and obtain a new trajectory that minimizes steering while keeping initial and final pos? Because what  you did was rearranging the differential equations

Comment: What I showed is that in fact, there are two independent dynamic systems instead of one.

Comment: Sorry, pretty sure is my fault but why two independent systems would help me? In case I can plug the dynamics I can just plug the original differential equations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99731/discussion-between-hector-esteban-cabezos-and-cesareo).

Comment: I assume that the input constraint should be $|u|<0.55$, otherwise one could just pick some negative value for $u$ which allows $\tan(u)$ to still be anything?

Comment: Yeah, is the absolute value

Answer (score 1):

In order to serve as an introduction to optimal control, we present a formulation as simple as possible, to the interpolation problem. In order to apply this algorithm, adequate discretization of the integral formulation will be necessary.

So regarding the interpolation problem

$$
\min J = \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2\right)dt \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\dot x & = & \cos\theta\\ \dot y & = & \sin\theta\\ \dot\theta & = & v\end{array}\right.
$$

with $X(t) = (x(t),y(t),\theta(t)), \ X(t_i) = (x(t_i),y(t_t),\theta(t_i)), \ X(t_f) = (x(t_f),y(t_f),\theta(t_f))$ with $t_f$ unspecified, we can formulate the associated hamiltonian

$$
H = 1+\frac 12 \rho v^2 +\lambda_1\cos\theta+\lambda_2\sin\theta+\lambda_3 v
$$

Here $\rho$ is introduced to guarantee that $|v|\le v_{max}$. The interpolation problem is solved as follows. ([see](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwit8MSj1JLlAhWjAWMBHVy6CagQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pages.drexel.edu%2F~hgk22%2Fcourses%2FMEM733%2FOptimalControl_1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0v6ZnOnDkA0-55PDUOVgzA))

$$
\cases{
\dot X = H_{\lambda }\\
\dot\lambda = -H_X\\
H_v = 0
}
$$

Attached a MATHEMATICA script showing a particular interpolation

```
tmax = 6;
rho = 0.25;
cart[x_, y_, theta_, e_] := Module[{p1, p2, p3, bc, M, p1r, p2r, p3r}, 
  p1 = {0, e};
  p2 = {2 e, 0};
  p3 = {0, -e};
  bc = (p1 + p2 + p3)/3;
  M = RotationMatrix[theta];
  p1r = M.(p1 - bc) + {x, y};
  p2r = M.(p2 - bc) + {x, y};
  p3r = M.(p3 - bc) + {x, y};
  Return[{p1r, p2r, p3r, p1r}]]

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Cos[theta[t]], 
               y'[t] == Sin[theta[t]],
               theta'[t] == -lambda3[t]/rho, 
               lambda1'[t] == 0,
               lambda2'[t] == 0,
               lambda3'[t] == Cos[theta[t]] lambda2[t] - lambda1[t] Sin[theta[t]], 
               x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, theta[0] == Pi, 
               x[tmax] == 2, y[tmax] == 4,theta[tmax] == Pi}, 
               {x, y, theta, lambda1, lambda2, lambda3}, {t,0, tmax}][[1]];


ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax},PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]
Plot[Evaluate[lambda3[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]

path = Table[ListLinePlot[cart[
   Evaluate[x[t] /. sol /. t -> tk], 
   Evaluate[y[t] /. sol /. t -> tk], 
   Evaluate[theta[t] /. sol /. t -> tk], 0.2], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red], {tk, 0, tmax, tmax/20}];
Show[gr1, path, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Cesareo . Some last questions for clarification. I still don´t understand why don´t you include alpha in the minimization while it is part of the state vector and I have a alpha[0] and alpha[end] fixed and your approach does not consider it. How is deterministically rho chosen to fulfill |phi|<0.55, as I don´t understand where your rho=0.25 comes from. Last thing, I was asking to minimize a steering of a trajectory that I already have but what you propose is to create a new trajectory out of scratch by just using first and last position but not at all my current trajectory

Comment: Please. Have a look at the optimal control principles in order to understand the rule of $\rho$ Regarding the inclusion of $\alpha$ as an additional variable, the process to follow is the same as the example considered.