# Path optimization with constraints

Tags: optimization, control-theory, numerical-optimization, optimal-control, python

I have a dynamical system with the following state vector and control input:

$$ \underline{x} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  x \\
  y \\
  \theta
\end{array}
\right] $$
$$u=\kappa$$

This system obeys the following differential equation:

$$ \underline{\dot{x}} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  \cos(\theta) \\
  \sin(\theta) \\
  \kappa
\end{array}
\right] $$
My objective is to go from an initial pose to a final pose while minimizing a determined cost function:

$$\min_{\kappa(t)}\int_{0}^{T} \kappa(t)^2 \, dt$$
$$\text{subject to} \quad \mathbf{\dot{x}}=f(\underline{{x}},u)$$
$$|u| < 0.12 \quad \operatorname{rad/s}$$
$$\underline{x}[0]=\underline{x}_\text{initial}$$
$$\underline{x}[N]=\underline{x}_\text{goal}$$

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386861/finding-optimal-trajectory-truck-with-constraints) they provided me with an interpolation problem to go from an initial pose to a goal pose, but in my case it has been given to me an array of N discretized vectors following the discretized dynamics:

$$ \underline{x_{i+1}} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  x_{i}+\Delta_{s_i} * \cos(\theta_i)\\
  y_{i}+\Delta_{s_i} * \sin(\theta_i)\\
  \theta_{i}+\Delta_{s_i} * \kappa_i
\end{array}
\right] $$

And I would like to make use of this discretized solution as an initial guess. The problem is that I would prefer to work in the continuous domain and once a solution is found I would discretized it (I have found solutions where I insert the discrete dynamics with my initial guess and I obtain a solution but do not want to include $\Delta_{s}$ as an optimization parameter because then I would be doing trajectory optimization instead of path optimization).

So as a **summary**:

- I want to obtain a continuous function that follows the continuous dynamics of my vehicle and where the initial point and final point are defined.
- I want this continuous function to minimize a certain cost function
- I would like to use a discretized solution that it has been provided to me as an initial guess (maybe interpolate the provided solution?)

Approaches I have done:

- iLQR and DDP to the discretized system using the original control input as first guess. The problem is that the control input needs to be augmented with $\Delta_{s_i}$ if we want to smooth a path composed of N points but we don't want to overshoot the target.
- Just consider a set of  points and using gradient techniques optimized the cost function and do reverse engineering to find the corresponding control inputs to reach each point. Problem: The dynamics of the vehicle are not taken into consideration.

I would be thankful if somebody sheds some light into my problem as I am quite stuck right now.

Comment: I assume that the cost function should be an integral with respect to time and not $\kappa$? Also, I think the discretization is missing $x_i$ (the right hand side would only be an approximation of the change in the state).

Comment: I have edited it, thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have tried yourself? And how familiar are you with the Pontryagin Maximum Principle (using the Hamiltonian as shown in the answer of the linked question)?

Comment: Edited, I am not an expert but I have read the theorem and the problem is that I am supposed to use a discrete path that has been given to me and optimize it, so it is not just going from A and B (as Pontryagin solves) but solving a minimization problem where I have a inital guess and want to optimize my path having fixed initial position, final position and while fulfilling dynamics of the vehicle

Comment: The problem with PMP is that it doesn't give you the initial conditions of the co-state. The discretization can help finding a good initial guess for that.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "co-state" and I havent seen how to include the discretized guess into PMP

Comment: Co-state is a common name used to refer to $\lambda$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how can I use the discretization to initialize the co-states?